# C# using Dapper and sql server scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, variables, dapper

I am facing a problem which is familiar in declaring a scalar variable. I tried so many tricks and searched in this forum with no use.

**Problem**

I am using Dapper in my application and after connecting to the SQL Server I'm calling a stored procedure to insert a company into the company table.

The stored procedure works fine in SSMS when executing it manually, but in the application it keeps giving me error you must declare scalar variable in `@comp_Addre`. All other variables working fine except this one and I really don't understand why.

**Code**

```
public void insertComp(string compID, string compName,  string comp_Addressing, string teleComp, string faxComp, string foundDate, string ownername, string license_ID, string taxingID, string licenseExpiring, string cb_country)
{
    using (IDbConnection Connecting = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectHelper.CnnVal("hrDB")))
    {
        List<companyModel> companies = new List<companyModel>();
        companies.Add(new companyModel { companyID = compID, companyName = compName,  company_Address=comp_Addressing,telephoneNumber = teleComp, faxNumber = faxComp, foundationDate = foundDate, ownerName = ownername, licenseID = license_ID, taxID = taxingID, licenseExpire = licenseExpiring, country=cb_country });
        Connecting.Execute("dbo.InsertComp @CompanyID, @CompanyName,  @comp_Addre, @TelephoneNumber, @FaxNumber, @FoundationDate, @OwnerName, @LicenseID, @TaxID, @LicenseExpire, @Country", companies);
    }
}
```

Comment: to add more clarification, i have all the connections ok, and if i remove this variable and all its relations the data is inserted successfully. Also i tried to change the name several times to ensure that no duplication in the name somewhere as a public variable which creating conflict causing my sql not to identify it... with no use :(

Comment: Change your parameter name to match the property name of your model _@company_Address_

Comment: My God ... thanks Steve, i feel a shame, how did i miss that!! ..thanks again. it worked fine, it seems because i got tired in changing names and missed it  .

Comment: I suggest you to avoid long lines of text. It is easy to overlook something when the text scrolls out of view. You can use the @ verbatim character in front of the string to split in more readable short lines.

Comment: Yeab, I shall do that, specially the other codes i still have to do are much more longer than this one. Thanks again Steve :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working Dapper & C# solution on my machine right now, but just by formatting your code a bit better you can see the error/typo in the code.

The code below should work, because I have changed the `comp_Addre` to `company_Address` in the parameterized call to the stored procedure.

Of course, you can also keep the `comp_Addre` in the stored procedure and change the property of `companyModel` to `company_Address`.

```
public void insertComp(string compID, string compName,  string comp_Addressing, string teleComp, string faxComp, string foundDate, string ownername, string license_ID, string taxingID, string licenseExpiring, string cb_country)
{
    using (IDbConnection Connecting = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectHelper.CnnVal("hrDB")))
    {
        List<companyModel> companies = new List<companyModel>();
        companies.Add(
            new companyModel { 
                companyID = compID, 
                companyName = compName,  
                company_Address = comp_Addressing,
                telephoneNumber = teleComp, 
                faxNumber = faxComp, 
                foundationDate = foundDate, 
                ownerName = ownername, 
                licenseID = license_ID, 
                taxID = taxingID, 
                licenseExpire = licenseExpiring, 
                country = cb_country });

        Connecting.Execute("dbo.InsertComp 
            @CompanyID, 
            @CompanyName,  
            @company_Address, 
            @TelephoneNumber, 
            @FaxNumber, 
            @FoundationDate, 
            @OwnerName, 
            @LicenseID, 
            @TaxID, 
            @LicenseExpire, 
            @Country", companies);
    }
}
```

Aside from naming the properties the same on both models, I would advice you to check out the naming conventions of the C# language. Reading (and enforcing) them will  make your code easier to understand across multiple people/teams and less typo/error prone.

Comment: Thanks Jan_V and sorry i didn't see your answer earlier. Actually I got busy with much longer codes since i managed to solve the problem by matching the name with the Model. I understand what you say, and this was a little miss because of the rush and also I am relatively new to C# but working on a project with deadlines. I shall be needing your help and Steve and other guys in the near future. Thanks again :)